# Sliding animation for ng-animate with ng-repeat not working but ng-repeat is updated

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

Consider the following [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rDQpPFJWein9rQ3Y3HNK?p=preview)

I am trying to have the `ng-repeat` elements slide left upon `ng-click`

I can see that `ng-click` is updating model, but the animation is not applying for some reason.

Here is the css file

```
.slide-left {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);    
}

.slide-left.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%); 
}

.slide-left.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0); 
}

.slide-left.ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide-left.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);

}
```

I verified that `slide-left` gets applied when I click the left arrow.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks